# When is ValidationTechnicalProfile executed?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

At what stage in the processing of a TechnicalProfile X is the ValidationTP or IncludedTP executed? Before X produces OutputClaims? After?

Say my TP has the following claim. It also has a ValidationTP Y. Can Y persist 'email' (is it available to it)?

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
```

Alternatively, say my TP X uses another Y as ValidationTP and Y inputs and outputs some claims (Input/OutputClaim). Are they available for output from X? Do I even need to mark them as OutputClaims if they are marked as OutputClaims in the ValidationTP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A validation technical profile is executed *after* the self-asserted technical profile, which refers to validation technical profile, has executed.

1. Claims that are declared as output from the self-asserted technical profile are passed to the validation technical profile.

In the following example, the **email** claim is passed from the **LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail** self-asserted technical profile to the **AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail** validation technical profile:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail">
  <PersistedClaims>
    <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" />
  </PersistedClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail">
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail" />
  </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

2. Claims that are declared as output from one validation technical profile that is referenced by a self-asserted technical profile are passed to other validation technical profiles that are referenced by this self-asserted technical profile.

In the following example, the **objectId** claim is passed from the **AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail** validation technical profile to the **REST-API-Signup** validation technical profile:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail">
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
  </OutputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
<TechnicalProfile Id="REST-API-Signup">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
  </InputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail">
  <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail" />
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-API-Signup" />
  </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

3. Claims that are declared as output from a validation technical profile *and* the self-asserted technical profile that refers to this validation technical profile are passed to other orchestration steps.

In the following example, the **objectId** claim is passed from the **AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail** validation technical profile "through" the **LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail** self-asserted technical profile to other orchestration steps:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail">
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
  </OutputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail">
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail" />
  </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

For more information, see [the **Technical profile flow** section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/technical-profiles-overview#technical-profile-flow) of [the **About technical profiles in Azure Active Directory B2C custom policies** article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/technical-profiles-overview).